# pseudo code to print the values 'v' of Hash table separated by comma without using concatenation/buffering

Tags: jquery, hash, hashmap, hashtable, pseudocode

Given that hashed object with unknown length 'n' with key/value pair 'k;v'

e.g {k1:v1, k2:v2,..kn-1,vn-1,kn:vn}

A function o(n) should output all value 'v' separated by comma (no buffering, no string concatenation)

How to include comma without buffering/concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repetitive prints?

```
print v1
print ", "
print v2
...
print "\n"
```

etc

if you meant "return" rather than "output" then I'm not so certain.

Comment: 'n' value is unknown and moreover there shouldn't be a comma after the nth value

Comment: "\n" here is as the character code for a line break.  The idea is that if you send each result to the screen/printer/socket as you get it (and print commas in between) then it will naturally form into the output you're looking for without use of buffering or concatenation.

Comment: thats right, but there will be an extra comma after the nth value http://jsfiddle.net/DK27c/1/

Comment: Not necessarily.  Have the loop print the first value with no comma, and then print ", " prior to each succeeding value.  Regardless, this is a valid answer to your question, yes?

Comment: how to achieve this when 'n' is unknown?

Comment: I didn't understand how exactly it works..could you pls explain how isFirst does that?

Comment: The idea is that rather than printing commas after each entry, you're printing commas before each entry.  All you have to do then is ensure that you don't print a comma before the first entry.  You set isFirst to true outside the loop.  At the beginning of the loop, you check it, and if it's true you do nothing.  If it's false, you print the comma.  At the end of the loop, you set it to false.  This means that, at the time of the check, it's true for the first loop through and false for all of the others.  Thus, every entry other than the first has a comma printed before it.